# plotly and week number line graph

Tags: graph, plotly, line

I am trying to graph the weekly evolution of the number of downloads.
I have data similar data for all o week year and plotly cut de line.

example:

```
Downloads_weekly=Downloads.groupby(['Week_Number']).agg({'Daily Installs' : 'sum'})
fig1=px.line(Downloads_weekly.reset_index() , x='Week_Number' , y= 'Daily Installs')
fig1.update_xaxes(
        tickformat="%Y-%W"
)
fig1
```

[image: plotly cut me the line]

Comment: Can you update your example so that it can be run as is and demonstrates the problem? I've tried your code with some random data points and I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Might also be good to share versions of relevant packages

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what `Downloads_weekly.reset_index()` looks like? Are there weeks for late 2020 and early 2021?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue- Im still trying to figure it out. What I think is that Plotly is converting the dates to months, anyway it becomes a big mess. The way I solve the problem is by hacking around it, I create my Year-Week columns

```
df['Year-Week'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y.%U')
```

And then I sort the data frame, and plot that

```
df.sort_values(['Year-Week'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```